# Python code with for loop that did not work

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have run the following code but it showed an empty plot with nothing plotted and I am not able to know the reason
Please help

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
for xx in range(10,100000,1000):
    plt.plot(xx,math.sqrt((.30*(1-.3))/(xx-1)))
```

Comment: See [pyplot.plot(...)](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot). `plot` takes list of values to be plotted. you provide a single integer. kindly peruse https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/sample_plots.html and the API of stuff you want to use before asking here. Thanks.

Comment: Questions that ask "please help me" tend to be looking for highly localized guidance, or in some cases, ongoing or private assistance, which is not suited to our Q&A format. It is also rather vague, and is better replaced with a more specific question. Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to plot each point individually, try using `plt.scatter()` like this:

```py
for xx in range(10,100000,1000):
    plt.scatter(xx, math.sqrt((.30*(1-.3))/(xx-1)))
```

If you're looking to plot a continuous line, you'll want to make your vectors beforehand and then pass them to `plt.plot()`. I suggest using `numpy` since `np.array`s can handle vectorized data

```py
import numpy as np
# Make x vector
xx = np.arange(10,100000,1000)
# Make y
y = np.sqrt((.30*(1-.3))/(xx-1))
# Plot
plt.plot(xx, y)
```

Answer (score 1):

While the other answer solves the issue, you should know that your attempt was not completely wrong. You **can** use `plt.plot` to plot individual points in a for loop. However, you will have to specify the marker in that case. This can be done using, let's say, a blue dot using `bo` as

```
for xx in range(10,100000,1000):
    plt.plot(xx,math.sqrt((.30*(1-.3))/(xx-1)), 'bo')
```

Alternatively, in addition to the other answer, you can simply use `plt.scatter` even for a whole array as following. Note, in this case you will have to use the `sqrt` module from NumPy as you are performing vectorized operation here which is not possible with `math.sqrt`

```
xx = np.arange(10,100000,1000)
plt.scatter(xx,np.sqrt((.30*(1-.3))/(xx-1)), c='green', edgecolor='k')
```

[image]